# Dynamics CRM 2016 for professional services

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to set up our software development company on Dynamics CRM 2016. I've customized almost everything I need such as accounts, leads and processes. However, It still feels that the CRM is designed for company with tangible products and shipping, etc...

Is there a way to setup Dynamics CRM for professional service company rather than product company?

Comment: Soon CRM will be releasing a Project Service add-on that you may be interested in. See "Project Service" section in the [release preview guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/B/62B3C32D-B17A-49EA-A049-21523EECA918/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_Spring_2016_Wave_Release_Preview_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Since the whole Service area of Dynamics 365 (formerly CRM) is *designed* for that purpose, I'd say definitely yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct.

You can perform many actions that a professional service provider business model contains. For example, you can create and/or schedule:

- Phone calls
- Tasks
- Appointments
- Emails

You can also use marketing module for your services. Campaigns and quick campaigns.

You can gather leads, work upon those unqualified leads and convert them to opportunities.

You can also record invoices for your services as your products.

And so on ...

And the best part is that Microsoft has provided so many customization and development options in Dynamics CRM that you can almost use the XRM platform to just manage any type of relationship management. So, you can customize or even add new entities and relationships to suite your particular business needs.

One thing to keep in mind: First, always try to map your business requirements on the existing CRM processes so that you can take advantage of the out-of-the-box provided processes and reporting.

**Update**
The deployment/set up procedure for Dynamics CRM is same for all business domain. However, you may customize and extend Dynamics CRM, put those extensions and customizations in one or more `solutions` and then import those solutions over the target instances.

**Update**
You may override product price on quote (for example) by double clicking the product grid record on the quote form. See below image:

[image]

Comment: maybe my question wasn't wasn't clear enough. I agree with you on the points you mentioned. I have customized many things such as the process from lead to opportunity and so on. However, My company does not have a standard price or a standard product we are a development house and we do customized solutions built mostly from scratch. My pricing is really dependent on time estimates and team efforts into the system. I came to conclusion that Dynamics CRM relays on PriceList and products stored in this list for pricing.

Comment: You have to select a price list while creating quote (for example), but that doesn't mean you can't override the price over the quote. I would suggest to define a standard price list of your (software) product and then if it needs to be modified according to customizations, over ride them in the quote by double clicking the product grid record on the quote form. See the image above, if this helps addressing your issue?

Comment: Also, you can select a Write-in Product from the "+" sign menu and the Dynamics CRM will let you write the product name right in the product grid. That means you don't have to select an existing product necessarily.

Comment: I've known a number of CRM implementations to only use __Write-in Product__ for these scenarios. You may also find it handy to define some standard offerings - Customized Software Development, Hourly Staff Augmentation, Planning and Architecture Support, etc - and then enter a custom price for each line item. CRM presents a lot of flexibility in this area to allow you to figure out the best way to use it for managing your sales process.